# Effect size measure for post-hoc tests after nonparametric tests: Alternatives to calculating r from z score?

Tags: nonparametric, effect-size, post-hoc, kruskal-wallis-test, friedman-test

I've calculated Friedman's tests for my data and want to report an effect size with the individual post-hoc tests that followed on from the statistically significant Friedman's test.

I use the formula z/sqrt(N) to calculate r as an effect size as recommended by Field (2018).

**Edit1**: The issue with the effect size that was larger than 1 was due to me not using the right N. It is now below one. Still, the effect sizes still seem to be surprisingly large, which makes me wonder whether the approach is really appropriate for this kind of situation.

**Edit2**:
After some clarification regarding the above, the main focus of the question has shifted to: **What are the recommended effect size measure for post-hoc comparisons after a Friedman test, a Kruskal-Wallis test and a Wilcoxon signed-rank test?**

The paper by Tomczak & Tomczak (2014: "The need to report effect size estimates revisited. An overview of some recommended measures of effect size") seems helpful for overall tests but I haven't found anything on individual follow-up comparisons. Does anybody have any suggestions, or is the calculating r from z score approach really the best way to go?

**Edit 3**: See @NickCox helpful reference to Samuelson's (1968) in his comment below.

Comment: Please give more details than Field (2018), including page numbers. I think you're referring to a popular but highly problematic text which often leads to puzzled questions on CV.  I have to guess that you're using a rough approximation that just doesn't work well for large $z$ and small $n$. The whole business of converting quite different measures into some supposedly universal currency is a dark art and I don't have a positive suggestion for you.

Comment: See the comments of @whuber within https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157217/transforming-data-all-variables-or-just-the-non-normal-ones

Comment: Thank you @NickCox for your reply. It is "Discovering Statistics Using IBM SPSS Statistics" 5th ed., pp. 326-328. the formula suggested is the one above. As it is common practice to report effect sizes in my area, I am looking for an effect size to report with the follow-up tests of Friedman's test, Kruskal-Wallis test and Wilcoxon Signed Rank test. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I have had a look at the referenced comment as well. I appreciate there are issues with the book. As a research who needs statistics as part of their work, it can be difficult to identify reliable (and at the same time accessible in terms of content, i.e. understandable) sources of information that help me to get on with my work.

Comment: I found another post that may be useful for some people with similar questions, although the statistic mentioned above is recommended in one instance in the cited paper too (Tomczak & Tomczak (2014): The need to report effect size estimates revisited. An overview of some recommended measures of effect size. Trends in Sports Sciences, 1, 19-25): https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/415037/effect-size-calculation-for-kruskal-wallis-mean-rank-test (answer by Sal Mangiafico)

Comment: Thanks for supplying the reference. FWIW, I am not a statistician either, but I don't work with effect sizes in this sense. If you don't get better comments or an answer, you might be well advised to change the question title, as the underlying question seems to be "How I get an effect size out of results for individual post hoc tests after Fa riedman test?". I am guessing wildly but I wouldn't be surprised by there being no standard protocol for that.

Comment: In that sense, the underlying question has changed a bit. Initially, I was really just wondering why I can get a result that isn't within the range of the coefficient. I will update it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The easier bit is that $r$ is bounded within $[-1, 1]$ but for the approximation to work the other quantity should follow suit. From Samuelson's 1968 paper it seems that for you $z$ should be less than $\sqrt{29}$, which isn't the case, so calculations before  your question seem in doubt.  Or $z$ does not have its common meaning. Ref for that https://www.jstor.org/stable/2285901